# Clarifying question about piconets and SDP in the Bluetooth networks

Tags: bluetooth, sdp

As I understood there are maximum 7 slaves in piconet.
SDP protocol uses L2CAP protocol as the transport protocol.
So communication between the device which searches other device and the searched device is available when the physical connection is established.
So I conclude that only 7 devices can be visible at one search query.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

SDP is used for searching the available services on a particular device.

For discovering device you will perform the Device Inquiry process, Inquiry does not establish a connection, it send the inquiry message and all devices listening for it (i.e discoverable) will respond.
So Inquiry can find many more that 7 devices.
It is only limited by the time for which you would do the Inquiry and the number of devices in discoverable mode and responding to Inquiry.

-Dennis